# Query to filter by '{Content.Fields.User.XYZ}'

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I'm been searching around, and I dont understand why it is, that if I create a query for the projection and I say I want to filter a field of the returned Content Type by a Field of the current user, that no rows are returned.

If I replace the token with a hard coded value, it does work.  I'm just missing some important understanding about why the token has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it works. You may use tokens in projections as long as they are not expected to vary per record. Tokens can be used if they are external data (querystring parameters, etc.) To make your scenario work, you'll have to build your own filter.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the filter, works very well, but still stuck on a bit of syntax, I'd wonder if you can help me understand what i'm doing wrong.  

var myField = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser.ContentItem.As<ContentPart>().Fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyFieldName");  

I'm trying to retrieve a 'Field' I've added to the User Part through the cms.. If I treat the code above as dynamic and reference by the various indexes, I can get the value.  

string v = ((dynamic) _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser.ContentItem).Parts[3].Fields[0].Value; @bertrand-le-roy

Comment: It returns null, where i'd expect it to return the field.  I think I'm not actually accessing the correct part.  So, to recap, I have a User Part with a Field from the CMS.  How do I format a call to orchard services to return the value stored in the field.   Thanks for the help, i'm actually making progress now after a slow start.  My company is going to use orchard to replace about 6 different sites, so all the sites are consistent, so I hope to be contributing back into the project soon, with modules that allow setup of more complex user passwords.

Comment: Try `dynamic user = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser.ContentItem; var field = user.User.MyFieldName as TypeOfTheField;`

Comment: That worked, thanks for much for the help over the last week.